# Let $R$ be a commutative ring of characteristic of $n>0,$ not necessarily prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$  be a commutative ring of characteristic of $n>0,$ not necessarily prime. Then the map $f:R\to R $   by $f(a)=a^n$  is ring homomorphism

As i know that if $n$ is prime is homomorphism ,,but is homomorphism even if  $n$ is not prime

Comment: No, since you don't have $(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n$ in general.

Comment: @Phil.Z..is there any counter example

Comment: Indeed for any integer $n$ that is not a prime, there exists $1<k<n$ such that $n\nmid \binom{n}{k}$. You could begin with the case $n=4$, and then find a proof of this statement by yourself.